# How do I make conditional statements within conditional statements work?

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a weather API for a site and I want the background photo to be related to the weather condition, temperature and time of day. However, when I'm trying to put the various conditions within conditions for it to work, it's not functioning like I expected. Here's the code:

```
if (hour24 > 18 || hour24 < 6) {
    imagePath += 'images/weather/night';
    if (res.weather[0].main === 'Clear' && res.main.temp >= 50) {
        imagePath += 'night.png';
    }
} else if (hour24 >= 6 && hour24 < 11) {
    imagePath += 'images/weather/morning';
} else {
    imagePath += 'images/weather/morning';
}
```

Also, here's the link to the repo: https://github.com/rise-and-shane93/adenaMaryKay. Basically, I'm building the file path for the background image based on the three parameters I mentioned. Let me know if this won't work either.

Comment: *"it's not functioning like I expected"* What *is* happening and what do you expect? Please read [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: Are you sure that the files `nightnight.png` and `morning` exist?

Comment: Do you really want to use `morning` in both of the last two cases? Shouldn't the last one be something like `afternoon`?

Comment: There's only 1 image extension (night.png), the reste is only paths. Is it accurate?

Comment: sorry to confuse yall but basically I'm just trying to direct it to different folders to select "morning" or "afternoon" folders. I haven't changed all of the file names but it's just to show the structure of the statement.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are missing the right path of the image.With the existing code it will
image path will be `images/weather/nightnight.png`

```
if (hour24 > 18 || hour24 < 6) {
    imagePath += 'images/weather/night/'; // added forward slash here
    if (res.weather[0].main === 'Clear' && res.main.temp >= 50) {
        imagePath += 'night.png';
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since OpenWeatherMap API includes weather.icon and wheather.id fields in the JSON response You could use them to set up Your background accordingly. It would simplify the code allowing to access images with the path like "/img/${icon}.png"

For more information see https://openweathermap.org/weather-conditions